# How do I access stored backgrounds on iOS, and change the device background?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm working on an iOS app to search for backgrounds, save them to the device, and change the default background. I need to know how to access backgrounds already stored on the device, how to save new backgrounds to that location, and how to set the device's default background from my app.

Comment: you should research before asking a question, you must show effort, not just say "I wanna do this, but I don't know how".

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

- There is no distinction between 'background' and 'image'. You can use any image in your photos library as the background image. So "I need to know how to access backgrounds already stored on the device" amounts to looking in the photo library.
- There's no way to access the 'set-as-background' method from a 3rd-party app.